# How to set correctly boundaries in canvas breakout game?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a game breakout in canvas tkinter but when I set condition to do baundaries the pallet doesn't move. How to write a statement correctly that it moves?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Move Objects in canvas")

root.resizable(False,False)
height = 500
width = 700
x = width//2
y= height//2
can = Canvas(height = height, width=width,bg = "blue")
can.pack(pady = 30,padx=50)

rect = can.create_rectangle(height//2,700,width//2,490,fill = "green")



def keypress(event):
    x,y = 0,0
    if event.char == "a" and x > x: 
        x= -10
    if event.char == "d" and x < 700 - width -x:
        x= 10
    can.move(rect,x,y)

root.bind("<Key>", keypress)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `x > x` is never going to be true.

Comment: To make the paddle move it has to be `x >= 0` and `x <= 700 - width -x`

Comment: Ok it moved but it still goes out of canvas field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive that, take the coords of your rectangle and check for the bounderies:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Move Objects in canvas")

root.resizable(False,False)
height = 500
width = 700
x = width//2
y= height//2
can = Canvas(height = height, width=width,bg = "blue")
can.pack(pady = 30,padx=50)

rect = can.create_rectangle(height//2,700,width//2,490,fill = "green")



def keypress(event):
    x1 = can.coords(rect)[0]
    x2 = can.coords(rect)[2]
    if event.char == "a" and x1 > 0: 
        x= -10
    if event.char == "d" and x2 < 700:
        x= 10
    try:
        can.move(rect,x,0)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        print('out of bounderies')

root.bind("<Key>", keypress)
root.mainloop()
```

I also added an try and except block to show when its out of bounderies. Let me know if any questions or error.

Comment: That's great but it reaises an error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Comment: I just added after try/except: pass to silent this error

Comment: It is because **if** the conditions arent met, x wouldnt be defined. Thats why I added the try and except block, like stated in the answer.

Comment: You also can add x=0 in the beginning of the function *keypress* like you had before. Its maybe better

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I fixed it, make - x, y = 1.0 or more, to start moving <3

#### Photo of fixed

[image: Photo of fixed]

#### Moving

[image: Moving]

If you want to move btw, to right and left, you should to this:

#### Fix

[image: Fix]

Comment: ok great it also moved but the paddle still goes out of canvas field

Comment: Fixed it! Check out the fix - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICBiT.png

Comment: Even now it will move outside the canvas.